# Adding a Button in the Status Bar

Tags: android, statusbar

I'm developing an android application where I want to add a Phone Button in Status Bar. Can I add a Phone button in Status Bar?

[image: example]

I want to add a button like showing in the above Image. I tried to do with the notification but the notification icon size is too small. How can I do it? Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think it goes against the design guidelines to put a button in the status bar since it's supposed to contain notification and system icons only. See https://material.io/design/platform-guidance/android-bars.html#status-bar.

Try a heads-up notification instead (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).
You can put the button in the action area of the notification (https://material.io/design/platform-guidance/android-notifications.html#anatomy-of-a-notification).

Comment: thanks for the reply. The system phone app is doing this. How it's working in the System Phone/Calling app?

Comment: @SushilSolanki Try this: https://v4all123.blogspot.com/2018/11/simple-example-of-heads-up-notification.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need foreground service with notification icon - 
[here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

Sample code for foreground service -

```
public class ExampleService extends Service {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, notificationIntent, 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Example Service")
            .setContentText(input)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();

    startForeground(1, notification);

    //do heavy work on a background thread
    //stopSelf();

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}